# Does Firebase Dynamic Links secure?

Tags: firebase, deep-linking, react-native-firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Deep links have a known [vulnerability](https://reactnative.dev/docs/security#authentication-and-deep-linking) both in Android and IOS, does dynamic links protect app from these vulnerabilities? Can secret information be sent via Dynamic link?